# Several instances of the same bean

Tags: jsf

I edit for adding new information : I try to use annotations like you said but it still does not work :

My bean A:

```
@ManagedBean(name="abean")
@ViewScoped
public class ABean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{b1}")
    private BBean b1;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{b2}")
    private BBean b2;

    // getter setter


}
```

My bean B:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BBean {

    private String a;
    private String b;

    // getter setter

    public boolean check(){
        if (a != null && !a.isEmpty() && !a.equals("0")) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }

}
```

But it still does not work, b1 and b2 are null.

But if I name my BBbean, my b1 bean is not null anymore :

```
@ManagedBean(name="b1")
@SessionScoped
public class BBean {

    private String a;
    private String b;

    // getter setter

    public boolean check(){
        if (a != null && !a.isEmpty() && !a.equals("0")) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }

}
```

So, I have the feeling that it is not possible to have two instances of the same bean ?

---

Original message :

I have several instances of one bean in another bean. I am not able to correctly use these beans.

My first bean A :

```
public class ABean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{b1}")
    private BBean b1;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{b2}")
    private BBean b2;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        b1 = new BBean();
        b2 = new BBean();
    }


    }
```

My second bean B:

```
public class BBean {

    private String a;
    private String b;

    // getter setter

    public boolean check(){
        if (a != null && !a.isEmpty() && !a.equals("0")) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }

    }
```

Both are in scopeView.

My faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>aBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.test.ABean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>b1</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.test.BBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>b2</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.test.BBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

In my xhtml page I have these two beans like this :

```
#{aBean.b1.check()}
#{aBean.b2.check()}
```

The problem is that the check method never return true for b1 even if this one is correctly filled.
Is it possible to proceed like I did ? And then to have several instances of only one bean in a parent class ?

Comment: You're mixing concepts I think. In your bean A you create both beans but after you rewrite that values with managed property injections, which are probably `null` at that moment. You're also mixing annotations with xml config, be careful with that. I encourage you to use only one of the methods for each bean. About injecting `@ViewScoped` beans in other `@ViewScoped` beans, this will bring you problems. Just inject broader scope beans if you want (`@SessionScoped` in `@ViewScoped` e.g.). If you have common code for two view beans, just implement a plain java class with it and make them extend.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I am sorry I am beginner and I haven't completely understand your answer. " In your bean A you create both beans but after you rewrite that values with managed property injections, which are probably null at that moment. " In the init method I have new instances of the two beans, so I thought they are not null ? "You're also mixing annotations with xml config" -> may you tell me which annotations ? If I do not declare ma beans in my xml the application doesn't work.

Comment: You're creating your beans by hand, but faces context doesn't have them. To use ` @ManagedProperty(value="#{b2}")` annotations you need them in the context. With annotations I mean you're using `@ManagedProperty` an possibly `@ManagedBean` mixed with the configuration file

Comment: Thx I have edited with my modifications